# Very slow assigning process in cython

Tags: python, cython

I have the following simple function written using cython syntaxes:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport cython
import math


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def calc_cy(float[:, ::1] matrix, int nXX, int nYY, float git, float dgit, float[:, ::1] bus, float[:, ::1] kapa):
     
    cdef Py_ssize_t x_max = nXX + 1
    cdef Py_ssize_t y_max = nYY + 1
   

    result = np.zeros((x_max, y_max), dtype=np.float32)
    cdef float[:, ::1] result_view = result

    cdef float tmp = 0.0, tmp1 = 0.0, pref = 0.0, dgit_u = 0.0
    cdef Py_ssize_t x, y
   
    pref = 5.1008 * 10.0**-5 * (3.92**(0.08 / 5.214 * (10**2) / (git + 78.05)))
    dgit = dgit/30601

    for x in range(x_max):
        for y in range(y_max):
            dgit_u = dgit * (matrix[x, y]**1.692 / pref)

            tmp = kapa[x, y] + dgit_u
            tmp1 = bus[x, y] - (2.7182**(- tmp ** 4.0 / 1.73)) * dgit_u / 7.13
            #result_view[x, y] = tmp

    return result
```

If I run this function for 100 loop with random variable (following code), it only takes around 0.09 sec. But if I uncomment "result_view[x, y] = tmp" in the line before the last line in the function and I run the same loop, it takes 2.7 sec. Does anyone know, why the assignment process to the result_view arrays is very slow? Any comment would be highly appreciated.

```
nXX, nYY = 999, 999
git, dgit = np.float32(35.0), np.float32(0.01)
matrix = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(nXX+1,nYY+1)).astype(np.float32)
bus = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(nXX+1,nYY+1)).astype(np.float32)
kapa = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(nXX+1,nYY+1)).astype(np.float32)
past = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    calc_cy(matrix, nXX, nYY, git, dgit, bus, kapa)
print (time.time() - past)
```

Many thanks!

I tried to recast the data type, but it didn't solve the problem. I also checked to make sure the data type generated by the function is the same as the data type needed by the array. I expected that the assigning process should only take 1 sec at maximum, but it is taking 2 sec.

Comment: You might consider examining the intermediate C code which is generated. This could provide a clue as to where the extra time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I tried all of them. Importing the exp function from cmath improves the speed a bit (~0.3 sec). The rest of them donot speed up the code noticeably.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I uncomment `result_view[x, y] = tmp` in the line before the last line in the function and I run the same loop, it takes 2.7 sec.

This is something seen quite a bit in optimization questions. What you're seeing is that if you don't use the result of the loop then the C compiler eliminates the whole loop body and it seems *really* quick.

The 2.7s is the speed it actually takes to run.

It looks to be like you're typing most variables correctly so there aren't any quick obvious optimisations.